# Can p-values help me deduce the following?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, interaction, interpretation

Suppose I set up a multiple regression with one continuous variable $X_1$, one (2-level) categorical variable $X_2$, and their interaction $X_1 X_2$.

This will result in four parameter estimates ($\beta_0, \beta_1, \beta_2, \beta_3$) and two different lines with different slopes ($\beta _0$ versus $\beta_0 + \beta_2$) and intercepts ($\beta_1$ versus $\beta_1 + \beta_3$), one line for each value of the categorical variable.

Now, could I deduce from the p-values in the model output that **I. the slope for the line corresponding to the baseline value of the categorical variable is *not* statistically significant**, but **II. the slope for the line corresponding to the other value of the categorical variable *is* statistically significant**?

I think not, because the slope estimates for each line are intertwined. But I am not sure.

Comment: When you deeply analyze what "is statistical significant" means you'll see that it is not very meaningful.

Comment: Also consider that [The Difference Between “Significant” and “Not Significant” is not Itself Statistically Significant](https://doi.org/10.1198/000313006X152649), which had also been [previously pointed out in a context that might resemble yours](https://doi.org/10.1186/1745-6215-12-264). Both articles are nicely written, but each expresses things differently (so one might resonate with you more than the other).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are correct. Assuming that the two categories of your categorical variable X2 are coded with 0 and 1, the regression slope coefficient for X1 will give you the slope of the regression line in the group that is coded as 0 (I assume that's what you mean by "baseline value"). The p value for that X1 slope coefficient tells you whether the slope is statistically significant in Group 0 (the baseline/reference group).

You do not get the p value for the same slope coefficient in Group = 1 in this analysis--only for the *difference in slopes* between the two groups. To get the slope coefficient and its p value in Group = 1, you could flip the coding of X2 (0 = 1, 1 = 0) and then rerun the analysis with the reverse coded X2 grouping variable.